# Oneliner to assert all elements of a list

Tags: ansible, assert

In Ansible, I'm trying to find a oneliner to assert that all elements of a list match a regex using a python generator.

Something like:

```
- assert:
    that:
      - (item is match('{{ regex }}') for item in list)
```

But I can't figure out the right syntax.

Is it possible ? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution: use the [`select` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) to reduce the list to elements matching your regex and compare the size of resulting list with orignal:

```
- assert:
    that:
      - (my_list | select('match', my_regex) | list | length) == (my_list | length)
```